# Equivalence classes in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: matrices, equivalence-relations, matrix-analysis

We define $A_1 \sim A_2 $ in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ if there is $G \in Gl_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $A_1 = G A_2 $. Find a distinguished element in each equivalence class associated to the equivalence relation $\sim$.

It is easy to show that the relation is equivalent. I have done that. Now what about the next? Clearly if two matrices $A_1$ and $A_2 $ are invertible, they are in same equivalence class. What about other cases?

Comment: If $A_{1} \sim A_{2}$, what does this tell you about the kernels of $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$?

Comment: @Peter dim of kernels must be same. That I got. My question is what exactly is the distinguished element?

Comment: Try to search *row-reduced echelon matrices*.

Comment: The kernels actually have to be identical, not just the same dimension. So we have the implication $A_{1} \sim A_{2} \Rightarrow \ker A_{1} = \ker A_{2}$, what about the other direction?

Comment: @Peter it's not the usual equivalence relation A_{1}=GA_{2}G^{-1}. Can I do row reduced echelon operation to get diagonal matrices here?

Comment: @Peter kernels are same implies images are same too because they are orthogonal components with direct sum of them is the whole space.

Comment: Row-reduced echelon matrices may not be diagonal.

Comment: @xbh in that case how would we denote the distinguished element for each equivalence class

Comment: @ChakSayantan That seems to be impossible. For example $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\0 & 0& 0\end{bmatrix}$$ lies in infinitely many classes when $x \in \mathbb R$ varies.

Comment: @xbh it's what the problem asks for. For eg if it was the usual equivalence relation A_{1}=GA_{2}G^{-1}, the element would have been diagonals with k no of 1s in kth equivalence class

Comment: @ChakSayantan I know, but it kind of seems impossible to enumerate all of them. So sorry about this. Or you may say that the representative matrix of the class is the row-reduced echelon form for one member in that class.